# Thread safety of NSManagedObjectID

Tags: ios, core-data, thread-safety, nsmanagedobjectid

Can an `NSManagedObjectId` instance itself be safely shared between threads? I know I could drop a level down and grab its `URIRepresentation`, but if I can avoid that I will.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. `NSManagedObjectID` is the recommended way to pass an `NSManagedObject` from one thread to another. The idea is that you pass the `NSManagedObjectID` across threads, like you're suggesting. [This CocoaCast](https://cocoacasts.com/three-common-core-data-mistakes-to-avoid) helped clarify that (and other common Core Data stuff) for me.